# IBM Worklight Java HTTP Adapters throwing UNEXPECTED_ERROR during Authentication

Tags: java, android, ios, server, ibm-mobilefirst

We are building app in android and IOS ,for server-side development, I am using Java HTTP Adapter. The version of SDK used on the client app side is 8.0 and for the server side I am using MobileFirst-8.0.0.0.

From the past few days whenever we launch the app, the client app is not  getting a response from the server instead it fails with the following exception

```
WLResponse [invocationContext=null, responseText={"errorCode":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","errorMsg":"Unexpected error encountered"}, status=500] WLFailResponse [errorMsg=Unexpected error encountered, errorCode=UNEXPECTED_ERROR]
```

I am not receiving any more information other than this. There are no other details which can help me understand

For server-side user authentication tutorial used is:
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/user-authentication/security-check/

Could anyone please help me with this issue

Answer (score 1):

MFP 7.1 SDK is not compatible with MFP 8.0 server. You need MFP 8.0 SDK to connect with MFP 8.0 server.

Comment: even after updating to 8.0 also it is not working @vivin K ..

Comment: With both client and server in 8.0 and if you get the response, you need to check the server side logs for further debugging. Update the question with the server side exception/error.

Comment: Hi Vivin, we don't get any logs on server logs, I tried many times, just client end they are getting above mentioned UNEXPECTED_ERROR.

Comment: In that case, please open a PMR/Case with MFP support. Quote this SO post as reference.

Answer (score 1):

The error that you are mentioning is from client side. Correspondingly in server side there will be error logged. You can view this log under mfp server deployment location under logs folder.

Comment: Hi Smitha, thanks for the suggestion, I will ask the deployment team to share me the error logs ,, I will  update after checking